# Not able to specify China Region for Azure Nodejs SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-node-sdk, azure-china

I'm trying to interact with Azure China Resources with Nodejs.

But could not find out how to authenticate the application with Azure China with nodejs SDK.

Tried `@azure/arm-storage`

```js
import * as msRestNodeAuth from "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth";

import { StorageManagementClient, StorageManagementModels, StorageManagementMappers } from "@azure/arm-storage";

const subscriptionId = process.env["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"];


msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLogin().then((creds) => {
  const client = new StorageManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
  client.operations.list().then((result) => {
    console.log("The result is:");
    console.log(result);
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: The China region Azure offering is managed separately (you need to sign up specifically for it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a subscription sign-up topic. Not programming-related.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Humbly, I disagree. The question is about how to connect to an Azure Subscription in China region using Node SDK. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @GauravMantri - ah - I misinterpreted the question. Yes, the China (and Germany) offerings both use different API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to `Azure China`, you will need to specify the environment. Please see the code below:

```
const msRestNodeAuth = require("@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth");
const Environment = require("@azure/ms-rest-azure-env").Environment;

const mooncake = Environment.ChinaCloud;

msRestNodeAuth.interactiveLogin({
  environment: mooncake
}).then((creds) => {
  console.log(creds);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```